# Trying to add multiple JPanel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I want to have 9 `JPanel` components on a `JFrame` and have 4 `JButton` components on each panel. But after adding 9 panels, 8 of them disappear.

Anyone can help me to correct this?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, your description is so poor, we can't imagine if you want these panels one over each other, in different locations. Try to draw it on paint, upload the file and update your question with the image url since given your reputation you won't be able to upload it here. Just share the link.

Comment: *"But after adding 9 panels, 8 of them disappear. .."*  **General development tip:**  If anything involves 'more than one', first get it working with **2.**  Once that works, it should be easy to adapt it to ..9 or whatever the actual GUI needs.

Answer (score 3):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, you may wish to consider using a different ones, compounding them to achieve your desired results.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

Comment: *"..you may wish to consider using a different one"*  Or, as we commonly do, use [**combinations** of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) (or a `JTabbedPane`).